# EF Core NetTopologySuite Geometry becomes geography in SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework-core, nettopologysuite

I have the follwoing `ValueConverter` class:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;

public class GeometryConverter : ValueConverter<string, Geometry>
{
    public GeometryConverter(IWKTStringConverter converter)
        : base(
            wtkGeometry => converter.ConvertToGeometry(wtkGeometry),
            geometry => geometry.ToString())
    {
    }
}
```

And this is the builder for the entity:

```cs
var geomConverter = new Geo.GeometryConverter(new Geo.WKTStringConverter());
        
modelBuilder.Entity<GEOCatalog>(b => {
            b.ToTable("GEOCatalog").HasKey(m => m.Id);
            b.Property(m => m.Geom).HasConversion(geomConverter);
        });
```

When I now start my server, EF Core creates the tables, but the data type of the property `Geom` is `geography` instead of `geometry` which is not correct.

Even if I do not use a `ValueConverter` and create a model whose `Geom` property type is of type `NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry` the result in SQL Server is the same.

Maybe anyone can help with that?

Comment: Show your model and how you have configured `DbContextOptions`.

Comment: you Can asigg data type from object or when declare objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, spatial properties are mapped to `geography` columns in SQL Server. To use `geometry`, configure the column type in your model.

```csharp
b.Property(m => m.Geom)
    .HasColumnType("geometry")
```

or

```csharp
[Column(Type = "geometry")]
public Geometry Geom { get; set; }
```

Comment: as soon as i am back to work i give this a try